# Сохранение стека вызовов методов в java

Tags: отладка, java

Как сохранить последовательность вызова методов java-кода? Мне нужно просмотреть, что за чем вызывалось с самого начала и до конца. Стек потока и пошаговая прогонка не помогают.

Comment: думаю это можно вкрутить с помощью AspectJ. при вызове каждого метода писать в лог название метода и аргументы.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
try
{
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Хотя возможно, я не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Или же есть варианты по-элегантней.

Comment: Нет, не то. У нас программа работает на винде и маке. С маком все ок, на винде падает. Я хочу увидеть место, где начинаются различия в вызове методов. Стек раскрутить под отладчиком пока не получается - слишком длинный вызов.

Comment: Выводите кусками и ожидайте нажатия клавиши. Используйте public StackTraceElement [] getStackTrace()

Answer (score 1):

В NT: RtlLogStackBacktrace().

Comment: win NT? под семеркой будет работать?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это плохой знак. Видимо, workflow приложения очень запутан и неочевиден. Как вариант, забить на поиск баги и выкинуть плохой код, а вместо него написать более прямолинейный. Если же хотите именно отладку, то используйте подробное логгирование на каждом этапе и поймёте причину.

Comment: код действительно плохой. А еще плохо то, что он заморожен и нам лезть в него нельзя. Если сможем показать где беда, и почему нужно разморозить - вот тогда и откроют двери. Вот только для этого нужно разобраться в диком вызове